# Signalr 1.0.1 Cross domain 404 error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-domain, signalr, signalr-hub

I have problem with Signalr cross domain usage. I have three different projects(applications) inside one solutions and use signalr to enable chat functionality among them. I have chat project that is separated for other three apps.

*This is code from it:*

**HUB**

```
[HubName("ChatHub")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
 {
    public void Send(PorukaViewModel message)
     {
        ..do some code

        Clients.All.addMessage(
           ... // returns feedback to clients
        );
     }
 }
```

**GlobalASAX**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { EnableCrossDomain = true });
        }
```

*And this is code from my clients apps,*

**Controller**

```
string chatUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChatUrl"] + "/signalr/hubs";

var connection = new HubConnection(chatUrl, useDefaultUrl: false);
IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
{
  if (task.IsFaulted)
  {
    //... I log error and stop connection
    connection.Stop();
  }

  message = "some message";
  myHub.Invoke("Send", message).Wait();
    connection.Stop();
});
```

This all working fine on my localhost, but when I deploy it on IIS I have this error on `connection.Start()`:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404)
>   Not Found.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Http.HttpHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0(IAsyncResult
>   ar)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)

I browsed all question and answers on stackoverflow but can't find any that would help me.

What am I doing wrong?

***NOTE**

With jQuery I modified hubs.js and changed this code:

```
var signalrUrl = $("#chatUrl").val() + '/signalr';
...
signalR.hub = $.hubConnection(signalrUrl, { useDefaultPath: false });
```

and use this in my communication Views, this is working fine both on localhost and IIS.

Maybe problem is in this line?

> signalR.hub = $.hubConnection(signalrUrl, { useDefaultPath: false });

In original /signalr/hubs it like this:

> signalR.hub = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });

How can I do that from controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is incorrect:

`string chatUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChatUrl"] + "/signalr/hubs";`

/SignalR/Hubs points to a Javascript proxy.

/signalr is the connection end point so the code should be:

`string chatUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ChatUrl"];`

Since the .NET client automatically appends the default /signalr URL.

More on the documentation here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs#hubconnection-api